# error: <destination> color.cpp:3650: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to record a video using cv2.VideoWriter but my frames are only 2 channels rather than 3 or 4, as the error describes.  How can I fix the frames so that they are able to be part of a video?

Here's the guts of my function:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("video.mov", int(fourcc), int(get_framerate(video)), (int(get_width(video)), int(get_height(video))), 0)
while(video.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = video.read()
        if (ret == True):
            grayframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            ret, final_frame = cv2.threshold(grayframe, 65, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
            cv2.imshow("frame", final_frame)
            out.write(final_frame)
        else:
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
video.release()
out.release()
return
```

The image is showing, but when it reaches out.write, it spits out this error:

```
error: /tmp/opencv20150506-38415-u2kidu/opencv-
2.4.11/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3650:
error:(-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

I know that my image is 2 channels, and I need it to be 3 or 4 channels, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: what are those two channels? you can use split function and merge to create new mats with any of your two channels but what kind of color model are your two channels originally?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but from what I've gathered from other people having the same problems, these channels are width and length. As you can see above, the cvtColor changes from RGB2Gray, so the color models are those I think. In any case, how do you use the split function and merge to create new mats? Example plz?

Comment: how can you have RGB in 2 channels? did you verify that it is 2 channels by printing mat.channels()? youll find opencv split code examples on stackoverflow I guess

Comment: No no, it's RGB2Gray, meaning it started as RGB and changed to gray. I'll try using mat.channels() and see what happens.